# "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method" without using local

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I want to query count of selected products with a Combobox in VB.NET, Linq and Entity Framework 6. This query generates error (cmbProducts is a Combobox):

```
    Dim Count = (From Product In db.Products
                 Where Product.Type = cmbProducts.SelectedValue
                ).Count
```

And this is the error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object CompareObjectEqual(System.Object, System.Object, Boolean)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

But when I run this query with *db.Products.local*, it executes without any errors:

```
    Dim Count = (From Product In db.Products.local
                 Where Product.Type = cmbProducts.SelectedValue
                ).Count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties and also in the IDE options, so it will be `On` by default for all future projects. If you do that then that code won't even compile. That would force you to do as you should have and cast the `SelectedValue`, which is type `Object`, as the actual type of the underlying object, which is presumably `String` or `Integer`.  You can use `DirectCast` or else `CInt`, `CStr` or the like to perform the cast, e.g.

```
Where Product.Type = CInt(cmbProducts.SelectedValue)
```

Ideally, you should be assigning the result of that cast to a variable and using that in your LINQ query.  It's important to remember that, while LINQ syntax is always the same, each LINQ provider has a different implementation.  LINQ to Entities converts your query to SQL that it can execute against the database and that means that some things that are supported by LINQ in general, and will thus compile, will actually fail at run-time against LINQ to Entities.  It's generally a good idea to keep anything remotely exotic out of your EF queries.  You'd probably be OK in this case but it's a good habit to get into as it can help avoid subtle issues.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure they are of the same type.

I think Product.Type is a string but cmbProducts.SelectedValue is an int, try to use cmbProducts.SelectedItem.Text

When comparing locally .Net will be able to compare them by SQL Server may not.

Comment: Thanks.But they are of the same type. SelectedIndex is int but SelectedValue can have various types.

Comment: That's not really correct. It is a typing issue but not the way you describe. The issue is that `Option Strict` is `Off` and the OP is relying on an implicit conversion, which is not supported by LINQ to Entities. A simple cast will fix the issue and `Option Strict On` will enforce that cast.  Also, there's possibly no such thing as `cmbProducts.SelectedItem.Text`, which would rely on late-binding anyway and may result in a missing member exception.